# Establish elasticsearch connection using nodejs synchronously

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have a nodejs application where i want to make connection with elasticsearch and other database like mongodb and then create server but i don't want to use **callback** functions .
is there any way to hold execution of nodejs code while function is establishing connections with ES cluster.

```
function loadConfFile(){

}
/* wait for above to complete */
function createESConnection(){

}
/* wait for above to complete */
function createMongoDBConnection(){

}

const express = require('express');
/* and so on  */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap into promise with async:

```
async function createESConnection(){

}
```

Use await to... well, wait until it ends:

```
let esConn = await createESConnection()
```

But there's a caveat: everything using that async function *must* go async as well (read "go Promise-based")

P.S. Hope you're not restricted to some relic JS version not having that